# How to I set the response of OkHttp REST call to a variable and use in another class file?

Tags: java, rest, okhttp

I have a block of Java code that makes a rest call using OkHttp.

How do I set the response to a variable and then call that variable in another class file?

Here is the code I have so far. I don't think this will work. Please help me fix and understand how to properly implement:

```
public abstract class PullID extends AsyncTask {

    String url ="https://exampleEndPoint.com";
    String id_needed = " ";

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    String doGetRequest(String url) throws IOException {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.body().string();
    }

    public String getPullID() {

        return this.PullID;
    }

    public String setPullID(String current_ID) {
       this.PullID = current_ID;
        return PullID;
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using URI Builder to make this easier.
It now works for me.